# How do I make a cross scene data save in Unity?

Tags: unity, data

I am trying to find a way to keep my "key" data from 1 scene to another. While removing the key from the first scene, and keeping the information of the coin being collected onto my next scene the things I find and try don't work. Because I want to use this information later, and whenever you change the scene it resets the scene completely.

Comment: [We have lots of existing Q&A about persisting data between scenes in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+scene+data). What *specifically* have you tried based on your research thus far, and what specific issue did you encounter making these solutions work for your needs?

Comment: You can use player prefs. You can save data to file or database and load it. You can temporary save data in objects that DoNotDestroyOnLoad. You can save data in cloud database and load it.